# finding instance in method_missing

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a situation where I'd like to be able to call

```
foo.bar.baz arg1,arg2...argn
```

at times baz will not be defined which I'll catch using method_missing however from method_missing on the object returned from 'bar' I'd like to be able to get to 'foo'. That is I'd like to get a reference of the object foo is referring to

One solution I can hypothesis is if it's possible to get hold of the binding object of the calling context/parent context. Ie that from inside method_missing to get hold of the binding object as it is at the point of calling `foo.bar`

So my question is, is there any way from with in method_missing, that I can backtrack (in this case to foo)? if I have to instrument the calls that's ok as long as it's done at interpretation time and not using #extend or something else that will blow the cache/impact performance severely.

Comment: PLease comment on what's not clear (making this potentially `not a real question`) I have a very clear goal so if the goal is not clear, some pointers to whats unclear would be nice :)

Comment: `I'd like to be able to get to 'foo'`is not clear. Do you want the name of the method or the object returned by `foo` ? From your comment to sawa it would be the receiver of foo ???

Comment: And are `foo` and `bar` methods that you master or also missing ones ? In sawa's solution you have access to self, which is the original receiver.

Comment: @BernardK I'd like to get the object foo is referring to/returning (not the object foo is a part of) 
foo is an expression. Could be a member, a method or any other expressions. bar I have full access to

Comment: Still not clear. If foo is an expression, it returns a value. You send `bar` to that value, so self inside `bar` refers to foo's result. If the value returned by `bar` is self, `baz`has access to foo's result. Am I missing something ?

Comment: But the value returned by bar is not self. It could be any value

Answer (score 0):

```
def method_missing *_; self end
```

Comment: In the given example that would return what ever `bar` is referring to but I need what `foo`is referring to

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyFooClass
    attr_reader :value

    def initialize(value)
        @value = value
    end

        # In order to say foo.bar, the class of foo must define bar.
    def bar
        puts "bar sent to #{self}"
            # return a class where method_missing is defined,
            # and pass it a reference to foo
        MyBarClass.new(self)
    end
end # MyFooClass

class MyBarClass
    def initialize(foo)
        @foo = foo
    end

    def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
        puts "missing #{name} in #{self.class}"
        self.class.class_eval %Q{
            puts "about to define #{name}"
            def #{name}(*args)
                puts "in #{name} on self=#{self} with args=#{args}"
                puts "foo is #{@foo} and it's value is <#{@foo.value}>"
            end
        }
        puts "after define, execute #{name}"
        self.send(name, *args)
    end
end # MyBarClass

foo = MyFooClass.new('value of foo') # result of an expression
foo.bar.baz 'arg1' # define baz for future reference and execute it
print 'MyBarClass.instance_methods : '; p MyBarClass.instance_methods(false)
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb
bar sent to #<MyFooClass:0x10195c750>
missing baz in MyBarClass
about to define baz
after define, execute baz
in baz on self=#<MyBarClass:0x10195c6b0> with args=arg1
foo is #<MyFooClass:0x10195c750> and it's value is <value of foo>
MyBarClass.instance_methods : ["baz", "method_missing"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the try however it will unfortunately not solve my problem. I can't change "MyBarClass" and need to redirect the message/method call to "foo"